# Probability that LM with lesser RSS has greater residual for individual i (or opposite sign)?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals

You have fitted a basic linear Model #1 (i.e., GLM with identity-link) based on observed data with residuals:

$$
Model 1: y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} ... + R_i
$$

A colleague claims to have a basic linear Model #2 which exhibits a better fit with $y$, i.e., "the residual sum of squares is significantly lower" in Model #2. 
$$
Model 2: y_i = \beta^{'}_0 + \beta^{'}_1 x_{1i} + \beta^{'}_2 x_{2i} + \beta_3 x_{3i} ... + R^{'}_i
$$

Before they reveal the model, they want you to estimate:

- (1) the probability for each observation, $y_i$, that $R^{'}_i$ has the same sign as $R_i$
- (2) the probability for each observation, $y_i$, that $R^{'}_i$ has the same sign *AND* is "absolutely greater than" $R_i$.
- (3) the probability for each observation, $y_i$, that $y_{i(Fitted)} - y_\mu$ has the same sign.

For example, Model #1:

- $y_1=100 ; \mu=50$
- $y_{1(Fitted)}= 60$
- $y_{1(Residual)}=+40$
- By definition, Model #2's RSS is lesser than Model #1's RSS.
- You and colleague use same $y$
- Mean of residuals for both should be 0
- You know RSS for your model and for null model
- You know sd of $R_1$ among your $R$
- You know sd of $y_1$ among $y$

**(1) Can we estimate the probability that $y_{1(Fitted)}$ from Model #2 will be less than 100?**

**(2) Can we estimate the probability that $y_{1(Fitted)}$ from Model #2 will be less than 60?**

**(3) Can we estimate the probability that $y_{1(Fitted)}$ from Model #2 will be less than the mean of 50?**

**(4) Is our colleague asking impossible nonsense?**

- Advanced extension: What if Model #1 and Model #2 (with "greater percent deviance explained") were both GAM instead of LMs, i.e., generalized linear models with identity-link?

Comment: All probability questions, to be answerable, require a probability distribution over some well-defined set to be specified. Exactly what is your "class of statistically better models" and what probability distribution are you assuming for it?

Comment: No, because you are describing only the probability conditional on a specific model. I honestly haven't any idea what you are referring to by "class of statistically better models": which models? "Better" in what sense, precisely?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this. Even if we focus on comparing two specific models, rather than an entire class of them, each model offers its own *distinct* meaning of the probabilities. Which "probability" are you referring to?

Comment: Let's strip to the essentials: compare the models $Y=\varepsilon$ and $Y=\beta_0+\delta$. In the first model let's assume $\varepsilon$ are iid Normal with mean zero and in the second model let's assume $\delta$ are iid Normal with mean zero (and almost surely with a different variance than in the first model). Ask your colleague whether you are supposed to compute the probabilities based on the $\varepsilon$ or the $\delta$.

Comment: Let me clarify the notation.  I am writing down the *models*, not data.  The models are what people use to compute probabilities.  $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ are random variables.  $\beta_0$ is an (unknown) constant.  Because your questions (1) and (2) ask about probabilities, they *must* use assumptions about one of these models. The models are not compatible, so it's not possible to use both.  Given that you pose a context in which both are being fit, *which one should be used to answer the questions*??

Comment: That helps.  But it would seem you cannot make any progress whatsoever without knowing the values of the extra variables your colleague is using.

Comment: Suppose your colleague's additional variables do help (on the whole) to predict the $y_i$ except for a seriously bad outlying value of those variables, where they predict $y_i$ badly. There's no way you can predict that possibility without knowing the values of the variables.

Comment: @whuber: It seems your instinct is we know nothing about $y^{'}_{1(Fitted)}$ or $R^{'}_1$. I'm not sure, but thanks for all your input! I look forward to any further ideas you or others have!